# add sonarlint in spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, lsp-mode, lsp, lsp-ui

I've seen a sonarlint config for emacs using lsp in this link of [github](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-sonarlint), and I've tried to install this without success.
I've already installed lsp-sonarlint using MELPA and I've added this in additional-packages config.

this is my config on spacemacs (I've omitted some lines):

```
dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
   '(
     auto-completion
     better-defaults
     emacs-lisp
     git
     helm
     lsp
     markdown
     ;;multiple-cursors
     org
     (shell :variables
            shell-default-height 30
            shell-default-position 'bottom)
     (xclipboard :variables xclipboard-enable-cliphist t)
     ;; spell-checking
     syntax-checking
     version-control
     (java :variables java-backend 'lsp)
     dap
     yaml
     treemacs
     )
...
...
 dotspacemacs-additional-packages '(
                                      multiple-cursors
                                      lsp-sonarlint
                                      )
...
...
(defun dotspacemacs/user-load ()
  (require 'lsp-sonarlint)
  (require 'lsp-sonarlint-java)
  (use-package lsp-sonarlint
    :after lsp-java)
  (setq lsp-sonarlint-java-enabled t)
  (use-package lsp-sonarlint-java
    :after lsp-java)
)


(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  (setq lombok-jar-path
        (expand-file-name
         "/lombok/lombok.jar"
         )
        )

  (setq lsp-java-vmargs `(
                          "-XX:+UseParallelGC"
                          "-XX:GCTimeRatio=4"
                          "-XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90"
                          "-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true"
                          "-Xmx1G"
                          "-Xms100m"
                          ,(concat "-javaagent:" lombok-jar-path)
                          )
        )

)
```

The problem is sonarlint-server is ready but I can't see suggestions of this. For example in this part

```
 public Maybe<Out> findOut(String key, String mapName) {
   return sharedMemoryService.getObject(mapName, key)
     .map(item -> (Out) item);
 }
```

In vscode or another ide in , I've received a suggestion about third line like this:
**Replace this lambda with method reference 'Out.class::cast'. (sonar.java.source not set. Assuming 8 or greater.)**

Could someone show me where my configuration is wrong, please?

thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution with help.

I was wrong in position of configuration.

the right way is:

```lisp
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()

  (setq lombok-jar-path
        (expand-file-name
         "/Users/myUser/lombok/lombok.jar"
         )
        )

  (setq lsp-java-vmargs `(
                          "-XX:+UseParallelGC"
                          "-XX:GCTimeRatio=4"
                          "-XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90"
                          "-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true"
                          "-Xmx1G"
                          "-Xms100m"
                          ,(concat "-javaagent:" lombok-jar-path)
                          )
        )
  (require 'lsp-sonarlint)
  (require 'lsp-sonarlint-java)
  (use-package lsp-sonarlint
    :after lsp-java)
  (setq lsp-sonarlint-java-enabled t)
  (use-package lsp-sonarlint-java
    :after lsp-java)
```